# Valid way to return HTMLDocument while cleaning InternetExplorer instance

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

Is this a valid way to return an `HTMLDocument` while cleaning up my instance of `InternetExplorer`?

```
Private Function myFunction() As HTMLDocument

    'init
    Dim out As HTMLDocument
    Dim browser As InternetExplorer
    Set browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ...
        
    'get HTMLDocument
    Set out = browser.document

    browser.Quit
    Set browser = Nothing

    Set myfunction = out
Exit Function
```

I'm asking because I'm getting flaky behaviours using the returned `HTMLDocument` later in my code. I will see the output `003`, but not `004`:

```
doc = myFunction()
...
Debug.Print "003"
strVar = doc.getElementsByClassName("sectionheading_center")(0).innerText
Debug.Print "004"
....
```

Error: `-2147417848-Automation error The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. -VBAProject-1000440-0`

Comment: Not like this since you're releasing the browser reference. Create a wrapper class where you instantiate the browser on `Intitialize()` and clear on `Terminate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will lose the dynamic interaction but can grab the html by transferring the innerHTML to the MSHTML.HTMLDocument variable. It is also only the body html.

```
Private Function myFunction() As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    'init
    Dim out As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim browser As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set browser = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    '...Other code
        
    'get HTMLDocument
    Set out = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    out.body.innerHTML = browser.Document.innerHTML

    browser.Quit
    Set myFunction = out
Exit Function
```

@KostasK's class solution is a good way to go with maintaining an instantiated instance as well as where you can add methods to that object.

Comment: I wonder if by transferring the innerHTML like we're discussing, if the DOM will be parsed differently than the IE instance? I'm using IE because a part of my user base will get different results in terms of parsing using HTMLDocument when I use ServerHTTP or XMLHTTP.

Comment: You are transferring from ie.document so you will have the document.body.innerHTML at the time of transfer as per the ie.document.body. If you want the ie html parsing, rather than HTMLDocument DOM parser, then simply transfer back into ie.document.body. If this is really what you want then working with a class is by far the better way to go and then pass the ie instance around. Note both cases have document.mode/emulations which affect parsing.

Comment: Just noticed, what's "SHDocVw" in your example?

Comment: It's the class. Good practice to qualify the internet explorer object with its parent class.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by the QHarr. His solution can help you with your issue. You can test it on your side. If still, you are getting different results then I suggest you share the source code. It can help us to reproduce the issue. Test results can help to understand the issue properly and can help to narrow down the issue.